# Help with matrix proof (style of it more than anything) eg: elementary matrix applied to matrix = matrix with the operations applied

Tags: linear-algebra

I only have these 3 questions (theorems I want to prove) so please avoid just answering them, I'm only asking because I'm really not sure how to lay it out or even consider it formally. Otherwise this would be "is this proof correct".

The three questions are (2 are basically the same... transpose could probably prove them using one).

1. The $i^{\text{th}}$ row of $AB = [i^\text{th}\text{ row of A}]B$
2. The $j^{\text{th}}$ column of $AB = A[j^\text{th}\text{ column of B}]$
3. If E is an elementary matrix (given suitable dimensions) $EA$ is the matrix $A$ with the operations that created $E$ applied.

An elementary matrix is a matrix created by taking the identity and applying any elementary row operation (any number too) to it.

All 3 are fairly intuitive (from experience) the 3rd the least, it is intuitive for row swapping and things, but a row swap combined with an add and it starts to look "less elementary"

I'd like to prove these (especially the third) in the style of "let $A=[a_{ij}]_{m\times n}$" rather than ... a method that doesn't.

(I have got a layout for the first 2 sort of. It involves showing the elements of the left hand side (row of AB) and the method on the RHS element wise are the same)

Answer (score 0):

For the third one, any row swap or subtraction or scaling, can be done by multiplying from the left by a matrix, so by breaking $E$ down into such matrices you would get your desired result.

But also remember that the order of the multiplications is **very** important.

And by doing these "left multiplications" you could use your 1st proof in conjunction with the third.

**edit** (this is what I think you're looking for)

Let $A=[A]_j^i $ then take a composed elementary matrix $E$ of multiple row operations, then $ [EA]_j^i=[E]^i [A]_j$.

Then if say $E$ swapped row $i $ with row $ j $ then we should see that $[EA ]^i_j=[A]^j_i $

Then also we could do the same, once with a row swap, once with row additional/ subtraction, then once with a row scaling. Then since all three hold, any elementary matrix is the composition of those in some order so the argument repeats itself.

Comment: That's the way I didn't want to do it. Imagine I learnt (and proved) the theorem "The inverse of an elementary matrix is itself an elementary matrix" later. If I did know this the proof is quite simply "Let $E=E_nE_{n-1}...E_1$ where $E_1$ is the first operation" then show $E_i$ does an elementry row operation (which I'm not sure how to do, show for row swap how (formally)? That's the bit I'm not sure about.

Comment: What do you mean by $E_i$?

Comment: It may help to know that a row swap matrix that swaps row $i $ with row $j $, is the identity matrix with row $i $ and $j $ swapped. And to add say row $i $ to row  $j $ you take the  identity matrix with a $1$ in the $i-th$ entry of the $j-th$ row.

Comment: An elementary operation expressed as a matrix. So for example if $E_1$ multiples the first row by 3 and $E_2$ swaps the second and third, $E_2E_1$ is the matrix that multiplies the first row by 3 then swaps the second and third.

Comment: I can write such a matrix and see why it works, I am not sure how to write it formally.

Comment: Sorry if it seems dense but what do you mean by formally?

Comment: In a way I can write down and call a proof, like I know it intuitively I can see that's what it will do, but if I had to convince others or write down a proof....

Comment: And you want to be able to express multiple operations in one matrix?

Comment: Not really, I want to be able to say "this matrix swaps rows" and formally prove that that matrix swaps to rows.

Comment: .One way would be that these operations are reversible, so apply $E$ twice for a row swap, and you will get the original matrix.

Comment: How does that prove it?

Comment: See my edit above